# Delete a row of Bootstrap Table

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Excuse me, now I am using this [Bootstrap table](http://bootstrap-table.wenzhixin.net.cn/). I don't know how to remove a row in the table, I have seen [one similar example](http://issues.wenzhixin.net.cn/bootstrap-table/#methods/remove.html) in the documentation, but I don't really understand what it means. Especially I don't know what `{field: 'id', values: ids}` means. The user experience I want to achieve is click button in any row that I want to remove, then that row will be removed.

Comment: Here is a examples of Bootstrap table usage: http://bootstrap-table.wenzhixin.net.cn/getting-started/#usage

Answer (score 5):

Get defined bootstrap table as variable.

```
let table = $('#table');
```

Detect click event with remove button

```
$(document).on('click', '.removeRowButton', function() {
```

In bootstrap-table elements in rows have data-index.

Next row getting clicked row index

```
    let rowid = $(this).closest('tr').data('index');
```

Built in function for removing rows

```
    table.bootstrapTable('remove', {
      field: '$index',
      values: [rowid]
    });


let table = $('#table');
$(document).on('click', '.removeRowButton', function() {
    let rowid = $(this).closest('tr').data('index');
    table.bootstrapTable('remove', {
      field: '$index',
      values: [rowid]
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 $(document).on('click', 'button.removebutton', function () { // <-- changes
     $(this).closest('tr').remove();
     return false;
 });
```

Comment: You don't explain anything about how it works. It does not answer the question.