# Bootstrap table .js remove event not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, bootstrap-table

I'm trying to delete row using bootstrap table.

**Table:**

```
<table id="checkDataTable">
    <thead style="color: #31708f; background-color: #d9edf7 ">
        <tr>
            <th data-field="AssetReference">Referans</th>
            <th data-field="Customer">Müşteri</th>
            <th data-field="ReceiverCompanyName">Alıcı Firma</th>
            <th data-field="Tools" data-formatter="StatuFormatter" >İşlem</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
</table>
```

**StatuFormatter:**

```
function StatuFormatter(value, row, index) 
{
    return "<a  onclick='removeAssetEconomyCheckBillOfLadingRow("+index+")'><i class='fa fa-trash fa-2x' aria-hidden='true'></i></a>";
}
```

**removeAssetEconomyCheckBillOfLadingRow Function:**

```
function removeAssetEconomyCheckBillOfLadingRow(index) 
{
    alert(index);
    $('#checkDataTable').bootstrapTable('remove', {field: '$index',values: index});
}
```

I can get index value in `alert` box. But row could not be remove.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem is in `values: index` it may helps you : `https://stackoverflow.com/a/64258424/11143288`